# ::grpc::ServerReaderWriter object cannot be called after a while in another thread,

Tags: c++, server, grpc

I have use C++ to develop a server based on gRPC, I want to store the `::grpc::ServerReaderWriter` object of every client connection, and call the object after while in another thread, but I got this error:

```
grpcpp_sync_server (4): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x1)
```

which prompts on this line:

```
inline bool Write(const W& msg) { return Write(msg, WriteOptions()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figure it out. I break the while loop after storing the

::grpc::ServerReaderWriter object

the solution is continue the loop and then the object is still usable;